# Find the most vowel words in the sentence (which can be several maximal words that are equivalent to each other and are located neighbor)

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, static

```
public class Methods6 {

    public static String getSentence() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("cumleni daxil et:");
        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        return sentence;
    }

    public static int CountVowel(String words) {
        int count = 0;
        char[] vowel = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
            char ch = words.charAt(i);
            for (char cc : vowel) {
                if (ch == cc) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static String maxVowelWords() {
        String sentence = getSentence().toLowerCase();
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        int maxvowel = CountVowel(words[0]), count;
        String maxWord = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            count = CountVowel(words[i]);
            if (count >maxvowel) {
                maxvowel = count;
                maxWord = "";
            }
            else if(count >= maxvowel){
                maxWord = maxWord  + " " +words[i];
            }
        }
        return maxWord;
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Methods6. maxVowelWords());
    }
}
```

If i write *book red friend* result is as expected, but i write 
*red book friend* result *friend* (so i do not get 2 words *book* and *friend*).
How i change these methods my get max. vowel words the same time,
Thanks for helps!

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? That would be the easiest way to see what is wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: Remove the comment at `maxword = word[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your approach correctly, looks like it will be 'somewhat' enough to turn `else if` into `if` only. But most probably there are better algorithms for the same task.

'Somewhat' because many times there will be " " (empty space) at the beginning of your results.

Comment: Yes, i always get " " (empty space) every result.But i do not another algorithms.Thaks for helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake in your `maxVowelWords` Method.

```
if (count >maxvowel) {
    maxvowel = count;
//  maxWord=words[i];
    maxWord = "";
}
```

In case the word has more vowels than the last word it does set `maxWord` to `""`. 
As Example `red` has one vowel, now it checks `book` this has 2 vowels it enters the if case and sets the `maxvowel` count two, but you set `maxWord = ""`.

Next you look at the word `friend` which has also two vowels and you go into the other case

```
else if(count >= maxvowel){
    maxWord = maxWord  + " " +words[i];
}
```

This would add friend to the output but friend would still be missing.

You probably wanted something like:

```
if (count >maxvowel) {
    maxvowel = count;
    maxWord=words[i];
}
```

This would set your maxWord to the current word with the most vowels.

Comment: When write if (count >maxvowel) {
            maxvowel = count;
             maxWord=words[i];
} i get first max.vowel  twice time

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider using stream API for this problem:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


  static int countVowels(String word) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
      if ("aeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  public static String maxVowelWords() {
    String sentence = getSentence().toLowerCase();
    Map<Integer, List<String>> wordsByVowelCount = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
        .collect(groupingBy(Methods6::countVowels));
    int maxVowelCount = wordsByVowelCount.keySet().stream().max(naturalOrder()).orElse(0);
    return wordsByVowelCount.get(maxVowelCount).stream().collect(joining(" "));
  }
```